# Upon whom lies the obligation to seek out the most reasonably priced repairman for damages done?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, torts-damages

If someone damaged someone else's property, and it can be repaired, upon whom lies the obligation to seek out the most reasonably priced repairman, on the person who did the damage, (the מזיק), since it is in his benefit as the one who is paying, or on the person who was damaged (the ניזק), since he must be sure that he is not overcharging the damager, or maybe it is the job of the Bais Din (rabinicle court) to verify the amount of the damages, as part of their job in carrying out the due process of the law?

Comment: Who says you have to use the cheapest repairman? IIRC in the case of a Doctor one can refuse "free treatment" because "you get what you pay for". (Or C&A - Cheap & Awful).

Comment: To me, this seems like a strict overall monetary / budget decision that the Bet Din decides. I.e., I would think that they would assess the cost of the damage, or in terms of repair, assess the average cost of repairing the item to restore it to the point that it was before it was damaged. Exactly how they determine this, is perhaps they ask a number of repair people for quotes and average it; I can't say the exact procedure. But, I would think that this is calculated into the total amount given to the victim. At that point, s/he can choose whomever s/he wants.